# Proof $g^{(n)}(t) = \sum_{|\alpha|=n} {n \choose \alpha} D^\alpha f(tx) x^{\alpha}$.

Tags: calculus

I was trying to proof the Taylor formula given in Evan's book, and I meet some troubles for one of my lemma.

My Claim was

> let $g(t):= f(tx)$, where $x$ is an n dimensional vector of form, $x=<x_1,x_2,...,x_n>$
>
> $g^{(n)}(t) = \sum_{|\alpha|=n} {n \choose \alpha} D^\alpha f(tx) x^{\alpha}$.
>
> where $\alpha$ is a multi-indices.

I was trying to show this equation holds.

Here are part of my work:

I was trying to prove it by induction on $n$,

I got to this step: $$ g^{(k)}(t) = \sum_{|\alpha|=k-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n} {k-1 \choose \alpha}  D^{\alpha'(i)} f(tx) x_i x^{\alpha} $$

Where $\alpha'(i) = \{\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_i+1, ..., \alpha_n \}$.

But I do not know what I need to do with $k-1$ and multi-indice.

I know my question might not be clear enough, but you can ask me and I will edit more details.

Thank you.